# How many abstractions in a containerized to backend and to comply with Zero Trust best practices?

Tags: kubernetes, security, containers, backend

I am building a web service that is a composition of a couple of containerized services. A few services are self-written in Go and therefore I have the freedom on how to make them communicate with each other.

I have a service A that reads and writes to a MongoDB. It offers a few endpoints that are hit by AJAX browser requests.

First I added a reverse proxy that also acts as a load balancer. My question is, for best practices in a zero trust environment, is that single hop enough? I mean, I could also add another service inbetween the proxy and service A that takes the incoming connection and does additional checks.

I want to avoid adding too many unnecessary hops, but I don’t feel happy that the user directly hits the endpoint of a service/app that has read / write access, despite having an authentication layer in the endpoint. Any help is highly appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

As long as you are following practices for encryption, authentication, and authorization you should be good to go.

## Database considerations

Make sure your connections to the database are encrypted, MongoDB supports both [in-transit encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/) and [at-rest encryption](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/) even though the latter is supported only in Enterprise subscriptions but you can achieve it with some infrastructure precautions, see below section.

## Application considerations

Make sure to sanitize parametric queries and use non-vulnerable JS libraries. Regarding this, there are plenty of solutions to statically check your code and catch the flaws.
Make sure to have a single point in which you are doing authentication/authorization regardless of the number of microservices that you are going to deploy.

## Infrastructure considerations

In general, adding hop to your infrastructure is not going to add more security to the systems assuming that no software is bug-free, so my general idea is to go for a few services but correctly configured. The more your traffic flow is predictable and lean, the less you are going to have trouble with it.
Assuming that you deployed your infrastructure on Kubernetes (given the tag you added) you can "play" with different levels of security by configuring your ingress controller in different ways, e.g., you can whitelist a CIDR of IPs or even adding DDOS protection depending on the Kubernetes that you are using (AKS, EKS, etc.)

Comment: Much appreciated for this detailed reply! Very insightful